# ng-model not getting passed in has-error class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `template` below inside my `directive`

```
<input ng-model="acc" type="number" required />
<p class="input-details" ng-class="{'has-error': confirm(acc, 3, 17)}"></p>
```

I have a method like this in my directive `controller` function

```
$scope.confirm= function(value, min, max) {
  if (!value) return false;
  return ("" + value).length < min || ("" + value).length > max;
};
```

The value is always passed as `undefined` in my `confirm` method, but when i call the same method in `ng-change` of my input like below, its getting passed.

```
<input ng-model="acc" type="number" ng-change="confirm(acc,3,17)" required />
```

Why is the `ng-class` not getting the correct `ng-model` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(""+3).length = 1 || (""+17).length = 2` because of type conversion see codepen for example crank the number input up and see what (""+acc).length equals and how to fix https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKQZoR

```
app.controller('classTesterCtrl', function($scope, $log){
  $scope.confirm= function(value, min, max) {
    if($scope.acc < 3 || $scope.acc  > 17){
      $scope.valid = false;
    } else {
      $scope.valid = true;
    }
  };
});


<div ng-app="modelTest">
  <div ng-controller="classTesterCtrl">
    <input ng-model="acc" type="number" ng-change="confirm()" required />
  <p class="input-details" ng-class="{'has-error': valid}"></p>
    {{(""+acc).length}}
    {{acc}}
    {{valid}}
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript you should have a scope for acc.
Also use data-ng-model instead of ng-model.

Answer (score 1):

Reference the `acc` variable using `$scope` instead of injecting it into the function.

```
$scope.confirm = function(min, max) {
  if (!$scope.acc) return false;
  return ("" + $scope.acc).length < min || ("" + $scope.acc).length > max;
};
```